# VBA - detect if user is running on 365

Tags: vba, office365

I need a way to figure out if user is running office 365 using VBA.
If I user Application.Version for Office365 and Office2016 they both reutrn 16.0

I also tried to read the following registry key

```text
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\ProductReleaseIds
```

but get an empty value. I see the key in the registry editor, but for some reason it does not read it. from what I was reading it looks like when running Office 32bit on 64bit windows it doesn't work.

read the version values using Application.Version
trying to read from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\ProductReleaseIds
```

using

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead()
```

Comment: I copied your exact question into a search engine, [this](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1491433) was a top hit. Does that help?

Comment: See [Access Version Checker](https://www.isladogs.co.uk/access-office365-win-check/) might be hints there. "Almost all of the information is available in various locations in the registry or obtained using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) code
The main difficulty is knowing where to look . . . :~>}"

Comment: Good chance [rubberduckvba](https://rubberduckvba.com/) might be able to help on discord.